# Can ear cancer occur?

Tags: cancer, ear

I often hear cancers of skin, glands, eye and other organs.

Is there an ear cancer?

Comment: Cancer can occur in any tissue in the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is ear cancer, both middle / inner ear and outer ear. See [Cancer of the ear](http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/head-neck-cancer/cancer-of-the-ear).   Most of these are types of skin cancer.

> The most common type of cancer of the ear is squamous cell carcinomas. Other types of cancer affecting the outer ear include:
>
> - basal cell cancer
> - melanoma

P.S. There are also heart cancers.